# Extract from a Dataframe Column a string that the pattern matches in a vector of strings

Tags: r, stringr

I have this dataset of columns, one is basically a quote and the Name of the state, below is an example:
`

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(num = c(11,12,13), quote = c("In Ohio, there are plenty of hobos","Georgia, where the peaches are peachy","Oregon, no, we did not die of dysentery"))
```

I want to create a column that extracts the specific state.

Here's what I tried:

```
states <- state.name
df <- df %>% mutate(state = na.omit(as.vector(str_match(quote,states)))[[1]])
```

Which fetches this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `state = na.omit(as.vector(str_match(quote, states)))[[1]]`.
Caused by error in `str_match()`:
! Can't recycle `string` (size 3) to match `pattern` (size 50).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collapse the state names in one string and then use `str_extract` to extract the name from it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(state = str_extract(quote,str_c(state.name, collapse = "|")))

#    num quote                                   state  
#  <dbl> <chr>                                   <chr>  
#1    11 In Ohio, there are plenty of hobos      Ohio   
#2    12 Georgia, where the peaches are peachy   Georgia
#3    13 Oregon, no, we did not die of dysentery Oregon
```

where `str_c` generates this string.

```
str_c(state.name, collapse = "|")
[1] "Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming"
```